# In Tensorflow what is GraphKeys.INIT_OP for?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Looking at the documentation for GraphKeys: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys

There is a `GraphKeys.INIT_OP` listed that has no documentation.

What is this collection for exactly?

I'm looking for the best way to add a few necessary assign OPs to the graph such that they will be run once at initialization time only. My initial thought was to add them to `GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES` which are run at the time `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` is run. When I saw `GraphKeys.INIT_OP` I wondered if it perhaps offered a more robust option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INIT_OP` should contains the global variable initialization op. By default it contains an op that when run, runs these two:

```
variables.global_variables_initializer()
resources.initialize_resources(resources.shared_resources())
```

`LOCAL_INIT_OP`  should contains the local variable initialization op. By default it contains an op that when run, runs these three:

```
variables.local_variables_initializer()
lookup_ops.tables_initializer()
resources.initialize_resources(resources.local_resources())
```